# New MVC 5.2.3 site not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a really weird problem with Visual Studio 2015. If I create new MVC 5.2.3 site (using the default MVC site).

I get errors as "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in current context" when I open any view (About.cshtml, Error.cshtml and the rest of them). I cant even get the default template sites to work.

If I create an ASP 5 website it works. But I need to get a 5.2.3 site up, and even the default ones dont run.

What might be wrong?

EDIT:

I've tried "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /ResetUserData" but I get "Unknown Error"

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it's working.

It coulda been 2 things:

1) That ResetUserData worked even though it said "Unknown error". Since the positioning of the windows where different than I had before. I ran that command prompt both as my regular user and administrator.

2) Or I was running Visual Studio as administrator and that somehow messed up the c:\Users things with me running as administrator, and then trying to save with my "regular" user.